# PHP a better way for check non-empty?

Tags: php

The common way for check non-empty var is:

```
if (!empty($var)) { ... }
```

Why can't we just use:

```
if ($var) { ... }
```

They're the same actually, right?

Ref: http://php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php

Comment: error reporting would tell you otherwise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!empty($var)` is exactly the same as just `$var`, except that with `empty` **no error will be thrown if `$var` doesn't exist.** `empty` is more or less shorthand for `!isset($var) || !$var`.

You should never use `empty` if you expect your variable to exist, because then you're just needlessly suppressing error reporting. Only use `empty` if you legitimately expect the variable to possibly not exist. This should rarely if ever be the case, if you're initialising your variables properly.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) for an in-depth discussion of this.